# Set the DATABASE_URL environment variable

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I am trying to create my own kind of project structure by looking at two scoops of django. The project structure looks something like this

.**envs**

.**local**

```
  .django

  .postgres
```

**.production**

```
 .django

 .postgres
```

in postgres inside local, the following items are listed

```
POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_DB=marketing
POSTGRES_USER=username
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
DATABASE_URL=postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/marketing
```

the settings file is divided into 3 parts as `base.py, local.py and production.py`

in base.py, I have configured the `DATABASES` key as following

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': env.db('DATABASE_URL'),
}
```

However I am getting an error

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the DATABASE_URL
>   environment variable

Though, I have `DATABASE_URL` in .envs/.local/.postgres, I am getting above error. Why is that so?

Comment: paste the output of command `echo $DATABASE_URL` from your shell.

Answer (score 3):

Add export before your variables in `.myfilename`.

```
export POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
export POSTGRES_PORT=5432
export POSTGRES_DB=marketing
export POSTGRES_USER=username
export POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
export DATABASE_URL=postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/marketing
```

Then do

`source .myfilename`

Comment: This first part is not too helpful as `export` will make the variables available for all sub-processes, however the user will likely not leave the shell. Sourcing the file with the environmental variables and then running the python script from the same shell should be sufficient. `source .myfilename && python myscript.py`

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1158231/2402281).

Comment: probably i missed source .postgres but in cookiecutter boilerplate they have not used export keyword.

Comment: it will only be available within the current shell it is being run in @tahesse

Answer (score 1):

I came across same issue recently. Your `DATABSE_URL` env variable in file .local/.postgres needs to be :
`DATABASE_URL=postgres://username:password@{DB_SERVICE_NAME}:5432/marketing`

As you can see here in place of localhost use "postgres" if your docker-compose.yml has service name as postgres.

Answer (score 0):

For a python based solution check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43934031/2402281) (credits to user @falsetru).

Basically, add

```
import os

with open('.envs/.local/.postgres') as fh:
    os.environ.update(line.strip().split('=', 1) for line in fh)
```

in one of your initial python scripts, e.g. `local.py`.